# Response Error: 500 after using CSV config data set in request

Tags: .net, xml, csv, jmeter, performance-testing

My flow is:

```
Thread Group
   Login page
   welcome page 
Login page has post method (send parameter with request - I placed variable ${user} and ${pass} )
welcome page has get method (there is nothing in send parameter with request)
actual welcome webpage showing user name, password
```

I am passing the value (user id and password) using CSV data set config to Login Page. This login page request running successfully but after this page Welcome page showing response code 500 error. I have set cookies manager to both request.

So what need to do to display welcome page with userid and password? Why this request showing me error even if previous page running successfully.

Comment: A 500 error usually means that there was an error on the server. You can often find out what the problem is by looking in your server's logs.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to pass not only the credentials, but also there could be a couple of dynamic mandatory parameters which needs to be passed along with username and password. Given `.net` tag I'm pretty much sure that server expects at least [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx), maybe something else. So your test plan should look  like:

- Thread Group

  - Login Page - GET

    - PostProcessor
  - Login Page - POST (username, password, viewstate, etc.)
  - Welcome Page

Where PostProcessor could be one of the following:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) for detailed explanation, example configuration and end-to-end demo of loggin into .NET web application.